# SQL Server Stopword returns no rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search, stop-words

I'm working with SQL Server 2012 and I have a problem with FTS search.

There is a table `[Table]` and I created a fts index for it

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [TABLE](Column1 LANGUAGE 1033, Column2 LANGUAGE 1033,    Column3 LANGUAGE 1033, Description LANGUAGE 1033, Column4 LANGUAGE 1033) 
KEY INDEX KEY_PK
ON FTSCATALOG
WITH CHANGE_TRACKING = AUTO,
STOPLIST = MyStopList
```

but when I try to find rows by stopword I get 0 rows. It seems that it does not use stoplist at all

```
select OBJECT_ID('TABLE'),* from sys.fulltext_indexes;
```

tells that index is working

```
114099447   114099447   1   5   1   A   AUTO    1   U   UPDATE_CRAWL    2014-06-02 17:04:01.050 2014-06-02 17:04:02.073 0x000000000001FFF2  5   NULL    1

SELECT * FROM sys.dm_fts_parser ('and', 1033, 5, 0)
```

shows that "and" is a stopword

```
keyword group_id    phrase_id   occurrence  special_term    display_term    expansion_type  source_term

0x0061006E0064  1   0   1   Noise Word  and 0   and
```

but

```
 SELECT * FROM dbo.[TABLE] WHERE CONTAINS (*, 'and', LANGUAGE 1033)
```

returns 0 rows.

Does anyone know why this could happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding what stop words are and how they are used.  The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142551%28v=sql.110%29.aspx#understand) is pretty clear on this subject.

Stop words are *removed* from the documents when the full text index is created.  Hence, they are not in the index and searches on them will remove no matches.  In fact, they are also removed from the query.  So, a query for the word `'and'` is the same as searching for nothing.  That is why nothing is returned.

Try searching for a more interesting word that is actually in the text.

Comment: Thanks, I expected that it should return all rows if there are only stop words